# SwiftUI ForEach fill to designated area

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-foreach

I want to fill a forEach loop on a specified field.

[image]

I tried to fit it in a space by trying VStack and HStach codes, but it didn't work. Plus, I tried .scaledToFill() and .fixedSize(), still didn't work.

Comment: Please adding this question to include code as text not image

Comment: Should the view scroll or not? If the view shouldn't scroll what if there are more items than what can fit the screen. Please be specific about what you want. Post the code, don't post the screenshot of the code. Better questions would lead to better answers

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. The example should be in the question as code not an image.